# What's the most common way of referring to the gender of a friend?

Tags: word-choice

I thought about 'male friend' or 'female friend.'

I've heard people saying 'girl friend' (usually girls say this).

What's the most common way of saying this?

Comment: I am pretty sure I've heard *guy friend* (as opposed to *boyfriend*) used for a male non-romantic friend. Of course, with *guys* slowly becoming a unisex term, this may not work for much longer. For females, I don't have any analogous suggestion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Female friend* and *male friend* are fine, but usually you don't say the gender of the friend explicitly. If you say *my friend* then later refer to that friend as *she*, it simply becomes obvious the friend is female; similarly, if you say *a friend of mine, Tom*, it's apparent that the friend is male because Tom is a male name. If you're not talking about a specific friend, then e.g. *I have a lot of female friends* is the best option.

The problem with *girlfriend* is that it *almost* always implies a romantic relationship: if a female says it casually, you're relatively safe assuming she means just a female friend and not a lover, but for (heterosexual) males it's exclusively for romantic involvement. With *boyfriend* a romantic relationship *is* always implied, regardless of the sex of the speaker.

Comment: +1: And OP should pay special attention to the last sentence.

Comment: I wonder if lesbians use 'girlfriend' to simply refer to a female friend _less_ than heterosexual women because of the implied romantic relationship.

Comment: In informal situations, *guy friend* can also be used to refer to a male friend without any romantic implication.

Comment: Note: In the UK *girlfriend* almost always implies a romantic relationship - the use for "female non-romantic friend" is far less common than in North America.

Comment: @psmears: I don't know, in my area the girls use it *all* the time these days, particularly so in the last decade.

Comment: @Sam Far as I know, yes. And hearing someone else use "girlfriend" without the romantic context can be jarring to a lesbian ear.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girlfriend) page makes a good discussion. Read it.

For some people there is a distinction between *girlfriend*/ *boyfriend* and *girl friend*/ *boy friend* (separate words), in the sense that the latter does not assume a romantic relationship. Also, the words  *ladyfriend, lady friend, guyfriend, friend boy* or *friend girl* may be used with the same meaning (non-romantic).
I have personally used the expression *lady friend* (but apparently incorrectly according to Wikipedia). *Male friend* or *female friend* sounds disagreeable to me.

Comment: In Australia at least, if someone says lady friend/ladyfriend/lady-friend a romantic relationship will be assumed.

Answer (score 1):

In many situations, the gender of the friend will become apparent when you talk more about them.

> My friend recommended this book. She said it was a really good read.

or

> My friend recommended this book. He said it was a really good read.

As I have come across it, boy-friend always refers to a very close partnership, hetero- or homosexual, girl-friend can be a partner for a man, a partner for a woman, or simply a female friend of a woman. But if a man refers to his girl-friend, it's normally not "just a friend".

Female and male friend sounds a bit too formal to my ears, but maybe that's just me.